# chat application as separate endpoint

Tags: node.js, django, websocket

I am planning to design the chat(web socket) application for my eCommerce django REST application. 
What is the best design

1. Integrate the chat inside application inside the same django REST server
2. Deploy chat as a separate end point for chat only. 
   If put different server and db for chat. how we communicate with rest sever to validate.? and whats the best design. ?

Comment: What is the current architecture & stack of your application?

Comment: current service is Django REST running on nginx with mysql. But I need a solution to be scalable.

Comment: and what you're planning to implement for `chat` app?

Comment: If you go to any ecommerce website. If I interested in the product I just chat with the product owner. he can send the answer later or immediate.  it is not direct chat like people chat in a room.

Comment: No, I was asking what db you're planning to use. Will it be the same as your main db?

Comment: plan to have the chat data in a separate database. but some conditions of authentication of the users will be done in main REST server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138890/discussion-between-roshan-a-and-shaharyar).

Comment: Thanks @Shaharyar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in Chat.

Here is the architecture:

[image]

- Your Chat app will run separately and will have no impact on your main app.
- I suggest using a different Database for Chat *(MongoDB recommended but you can create separate MySQL DB too)* to not put Chat burden on main DB.
- Keep the authentications on REST server and not allow Chat server to access main DB. Create an endpoint when you need it.
- You can move Chat to a different server too in future, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

For these types of real-time application, you should be using websocket.
Since, you are using django, I would recommend you to try [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)